# Dynamic Updating Annoyance

Tags: dynamic

I want to use the following grid of Dynamic variables to set values for evaluations of expressions containing those variables.

```
Grid[
 {{"Index name",InputField[Dynamic[name],String]}
, {"Index shares", RadioButtonBar[Dynamic[shares], {True -> 
 "Separate",False -> "Combined"}]}
,{"Global data",RadioButtonBar[Dynamic[global], {separate -> "Separate", 
   combined -> "Combined"}]}
, {"Currency", RadioButtonBar[Dynamic[currency], {usd -> "USD", 
 euro-> "EURO"}]}},
Frame -> All, FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 12], 
Alignment -> Left, ItemStyle -> 14, Background -> LightBlue
]
```

[image]

When I open the notebook, or even an otherwise empty notebook with this code, it hangs for a while, then displays the "Disable Dynamic Evaluation" dialog box, and continues to hang for another minute, before allowing me to click the disable dynamic button. Then the notebook becomes usable.

At that point, I can re-enable dynamic evaluation, evaluate the grid and it's expressions, and the notebook works properly. How can I fix this?

Comment: What version of *Mma*? I don't have a problem.  Note that the code does not create exactly the image shown, just in case it's the code for the image that is causing the problem.

Comment: It's 12.0.  I shortened some of the variable names and text strings to make the code be more readable in the post. I don't think I changed anything significant.

Comment: So this exact example produces the same problem?

Comment: I didn't notice any slowdown with that code under Windows 10. Did you have other notebooks open at the time? My Mathematica gets very slow when I have many notebooks open.

Comment: Because of @MichaelE2 comment, I thought that the problem might be due to Mathematica and not the code, so I restarted Mathematica with a shift-control click. The Dynamic Evaluation problem went away.